# Getting AccountPendingMigrationToSrp The specified account is pending migration to SRP error for azure storage accounts

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-storage

We are implementing scaleup/scaledown schedule options for my storage account with the help of Rest API. we are getting below error while scaling up the storage account from General purpose V2 to General purpose V2.

```
"statusMessage": "{\"error\":{\"code\":\"AccountPendingMigrationToSrp\",\"message\":\"AccountPendingMigrationToSrp The specified account is pending migration to SRP.\"}}",
```

I have tried below powershell command to abort the migration of Storage account.

```
Move-AzureStorageAccount -Abort -StorageAccountName "1sdeveloper"
```

however, still facing the error like below:

WARNING: Because the Az modules have all the capabilities of AzureRM modules and more, we will retire the AzureRM modules on 29 February 2024. Learn more about the migration to Az:
http://aka.ms/azpsmigrate.
Move-AzureStorageAccount : No default subscription has been designated. Use Select-

```
AzureSubscription -Default <subscriptionName> to set the default subscription.
At line:1 char:1
+ Move-AzureStorageAccount -Abort -StorageAccountName "1sdeveloper"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Move-AzureStorageAccount], ApplicationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.ServiceManagement.StorageServices.MoveStorageAccountCommand
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the workaround you can follow,

As you have not mentioned the RestAPI, You can use below to [***upgrade the storage***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storagerp/storage-accounts/update#storageaccountupdate) to `General Purpose v2` using **`PATCH`** method.

```
   PATCH https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscription-id}/resourceGroups/res9407/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/sto8596?api-version=2021-09-01
```

Alternatively ,***If you want to to use CLI to upgrade general purpose v1 to general purpose v2 below is the `Cmd`***.

```
az storage account update -g <resource-group> -n <storage-account> --set kind=StorageV2 --access-tier=<Hot/Cool>
```

***NOTE:-*** ***Only Storage v2 value will allow for the aforementioned statements.***

For more information please refer this [**MICROSOFT DOCUMENTATION**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-account-upgrade?tabs=azure-cli#upgrade-an-account).